# navbar is in front and doesn't allow div below it

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm new to Bootstrap and I have a problem, I have a navbar where everything I put goes behind it and even with margin and native bs padding at most it doesn't stay at the distance I want, since the div I want moving on the y axis is counting from the beginning of the page and not from the nearest div, which would be the navbar

[Current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebG70.png)
The red line is where I want the white background to start

My code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<body class="pt-5">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand me-auto" href="#">Zello Painel</a>
      <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
          <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Zello Painel</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
          <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center flex-grow-1 pe-3">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link mx-lg-2" aria-current="page" href="index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <!--MUDEI AQUI-->
              <a class="nav-link mx-lg-2" href="#">Funcionários</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <!--MUDEI AQUI-->
              <a class="nav-link mx-lg-2 active" href="encurtador.php">Encurtador</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <!--MUDEI AQUI-->
              <a class="nav-link mx-lg-2" href="#">teste</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <!--MUDEI AQUI-->
              <a class="nav-link mx-lg-2" href="#">teste</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <!--MUDEI AQUI-->
              <a class="nav-link mx-lg-2" href="#">teste</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <!--MUDEI AQUI-->
              <a class="nav-link mx-lg-2" href="#">teste</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="../php/logout.php" class="login-button">Sair</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <header class="bg-light py-5">
    <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 my-5">
      <div class="text-center text-white">
        <h1 class="display-4 fw-bolder text-danger">Shop in style</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fixed-top` bootstrap class will make the element's position of type `fixed`, meaning it will stay in the same spot regardless of scrolling and also not affect the position of other elements. You probably want to use `relative` or `sticky` positioning instead.

I'd recommend trying one of these:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg position-sticky">
...
</nav>
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg position-relative">
...
</nav>
```

See also:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Also, if you don't really care about the elements overlapping, the z-index css property may also be relevant to you. This property can force elements to render in a different order than default (usually an element declared after another will be on top of it). However, this would be a hackier fix in my opinion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index